# Add summary from R to excel

Tags: r, excel

I want do some data analysis and write the result to a excel file. I know how to add dataFrame but I don't know how to add, for example a summary of an object, to a sheet

For example, suppose that I have a dataFrame dF

```
Pr <- lm(Power~a + b + c,data = dF)  
r <- predict(Pr,interval="prediction")
r<-data.frame(r)

Excel1 <- createWorkbook()
Data <- createSheet(Excel1, sheetName = "Data")
Result <- createSheet(Excel1, sheetName = "Results")
Summary <- createSheet(Excel1, sheetName = "Summary")
addDataFrame(dF,Data)
addDataFrame(r,Result)

saveWorkbook(Excel1, "Excel1")
```

Now how to add summary(Pr) into the sheet "Summary" ? Please help

Comment: trying to integrate Excel into a non-Microsoft-workflow is the portal to world of pain and suffering - import as CSV, work with ODF, ...

Comment: look at the components of the `summary` object (with `str`, or `unclass`) and decide which ones you want to pull out and put in your Excel file -- make them into a data frame.  Or use `capture.output(summary(Pr))` to get the output as a character variable.

Comment: Thanks Ben Bolker. After capturing the output of summary(Pr) how to insert it in a sheet of excel ?

Comment: I got a working solution data.frame(as.matrix(capture.output(summary(Pr))))

Comment: @Tulip For the sake of good order, please feel free to write this as an answer and check it correct.